# Best algorithm to activate user's account

Tags: php, algorithm, email, account

I have a website like SO. When users create an account, their accounts is deactivated until opening their emails and click on such an URL that I sent before.

Well, that URL should be containing what parameters?

---

currently I hash user's email and pass it as a parameter to that URL. So when user clicks on it, I get that hashed-email and compare it. But my algorithm isn't good, because user can hash himself-email and pass it to my script, without opening his email. Well I want to know, how can I make a confirm-account-url and how do I validate it?

Comment: You need to hash it along with something random that only the app knows.

Comment: Look at salting hashes. [This post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure-for-password-storage) refers to passwords, but you can use the same method for your single use activation link. Then you can just store the key in your database until its used, then remove the record.

Comment: It's usually best to also have an expiration date, so that after a while you can do a cleanup in your db deleting all of the expired (non-activated) accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a random string, and store it in the database, in the user's record. Then send the email with a URL containing that string. So you can easily lookup for that string in the database, and activate the account.